# Wordpress Source code of a page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change something on a page , but I need to do this inside the source code of the page.I tried appearance->editor but there are lots of source codes there.
The change I want to do is to change the name of menu item download to outcomes . But I guess I need to do it inside the source code so could you help me finds the source code  ? There are 10 pages .The page I need to change is home page.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change the name of the menu item, you don't have to edit the source code. Login to the admin dashboard and navigate to the `Appearance` > `Menus` section.

Comment: http://www.intouch-ict.eu/ in this page I want to change the name Downloads to Outcomes at the right top corner

Comment: I see that the text is changed to 'Outcomes' now. Is your issue resolved?